# multiple approaches/ways to prove that $1000^N - 1$ cannot be a divisor of $1978^N - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, natural-numbers

Am interested in learning  to do multiple proofs for the same problem, and hence I chose this problem:

> Prove that for any natural number $N$,
>
> $1000^N - 1$ cannot be a divisor of $1978^N - 1$.

I'd like to learn how to prove such a statement in more than one way (approach).

Comment: Welcome, user48390! I take it you're interested in learning how to prove a conjecture using different proof approaches/methods? Do you know of any proofs of your statement, so we don't duplicate what you already might know?

Comment: What does it mean to be a divisor "in more than one way"?

Comment: @EuYu, I think the OP means using more than one approach (to prove it.  I'll edit, to clarify. user48390, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ Examining their factorizations for small $\rm\,N\,$ shows that the power of $3$ dividing the former exceeds that of the latter (by $2),$ so the former cannot divide the latter. It suffices to prove by induction that this pattern persists (which requires only simple number theory).

Comment: Further (general purpose) hint: use [LTE = Lifting The Exponent](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h401494) to compute the power of 3 dividing each.