# Prove that for any natural number $n$, $1000^n-1$ is not a divisor of $1978^n-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

This question was asked 7 years ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231355/multiple-approaches-ways-to-prove-that-1000n-1-cannot-be-a-divisor-of-1978) and the answer has left me more stumped than I was before.

How is something like this proven?

Comment: Further (general purpose) hint: use [LTE - Lifting The Exponent](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h401494) to compute the power of $3$ dividing each.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that if $n$ is a multiple of $1, 3, 9, 27, ...$, respectively,

then $1000^n-1$ is a multiple of $27, 81, 243, 729, ...$, respectively,

but the  powers of $3$ dividing $1978^n-1$ are only $3, 9, 27, 81, ..., $ respectively;

but if $1000^n-1$ were a divisor of $1978^n-1$,

then any factor of $1000^n-1$ would be a factor of $1978^n-1$.

Comment: How are factors of 1978^n-1 found? The factors of 1000^n-1 make sense.

Comment: $3$ but not $9$ divides $1978-1$, so $9$ but not $27$ divides $1978^3-1=(1978-1)(1978^2+1978+1)$, so $27$ but not $81$ divides $1978^9-1=(1978^3-1)(1978^6+1978^3+1)$, etc.